# Understanding theorem on expected value of a function $E(h(X))$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

The theorem states:

> *Let X, Y be random variables defined over $(\Omega,\Im,P)$ and $h$ a real-valued function such that $h(X)$ is a random variable. If $E(h(X))$ exists, then: $E(h(X))=E(E(h(X))|Y).$*

I don't understand the beginning of the proof:

$$E(E(h(X))|Y) = \sum\limits_y E(h(X)|Y=y)P(Y=y)$$

I don't know how to get from the definition of conditional expected value to the last equation. I appreciate your help.

Comment: These are discrete random variables?

Comment: Yes. It's the part of the proof for discrete random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
E[h(X)|Y]
$$
is a random variable: it has the form
$$
E[h(X)|Y] = g(Y)
$$for some deterministic function $g$.

So, the randomness of this random variable does only depend on $Y$:
$$
E[h(X)|Y](\omega) = g(Y(\omega))
$$
and so the expected value is
$$
E[E[h(X)|Y]] =E[g(Y)] = \sum P(Y = y) g(y)
$$
now the strange notation is
$$
E[h(X)|Y=y] = g(y)
$$
and you get
$$
E[E[h(X)|Y]] =\sum P(Y = y) E[h(X)|Y=y]$$

Comment: Hmm I was thinking how could I get to that expression by definition: $E(E(h(X))|Y)=E(\sum\limits_xh(X)P(X=x|Y=y))$ But I can't go further from there.

Comment: did you read my message?

Comment: Yes, and I realised that both of us are wrong: We are beginning with $E(h(X)|Y)$ instead of $E(h(X))|Y$. So that'd give: $$E(E(h(X))|Y)=E\left(\left(\sum\limits_x h(x)P(X=x)\right) | Y\right).$$

Comment: E(h(X)) | Y does not make much sense.

Comment: So probably a print error?

Comment: It was a print error. My teacher (the author of the book) was quite surprised. Thanks mookid.